# forceManyBody filtered in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3 v4 for a directional graph with nodes and arrows.

Basically I use this example:

- https://bl.ocks.org/puzzler10/4438752bb93f45dc5ad5214efaa12e4a

But I remove the drag "end" event with the purpose to fix the nodes on drag.

The idea is that at the beginning the nodes are not fixed with the simulation but then, after drag, save the positions of the fixed nodes.

But, I have a problem with the forces:

Is doing the d3.forceManyBody; and this method is applying forces to each node. But instead, I want that only generate forces to other nodes all these nodes that are not fixed.

How can I do this?

```js
//create somewhere to put the force directed graph
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");
    
var radius = 15; 

var nodes_data =  [
    {"name": "Lillian", "sex": "F"},
    {"name": "Gordon", "sex": "M"},
    {"name": "Sylvester", "sex": "M"},
    {"name": "Mary", "sex": "F"},
    {"name": "Helen", "sex": "F"},
    {"name": "Jamie", "sex": "M"},
    {"name": "Jessie", "sex": "F"},
    {"name": "Ashton", "sex": "M"},
    {"name": "Duncan", "sex": "M"},
    {"name": "Evette", "sex": "F"},
    {"name": "Mauer", "sex": "M"},
    {"name": "Fray", "sex": "F"},
    {"name": "Duke", "sex": "M"},
    {"name": "Baron", "sex": "M"},
    {"name": "Infante", "sex": "M"},
    {"name": "Percy", "sex": "M"},
    {"name": "Cynthia", "sex": "F"},
    {"name": "Feyton", "sex": "M"},
    {"name": "Lesley", "sex": "F"},
    {"name": "Yvette", "sex": "F"},
    {"name": "Maria", "sex": "F"},
    {"name": "Lexy", "sex": "F"},
    {"name": "Peter", "sex": "M"},
    {"name": "Ashley", "sex": "F"},
    {"name": "Finkler", "sex": "M"},
    {"name": "Damo", "sex": "M"},
    {"name": "Imogen", "sex": "F"}
    ]

//Sample links data 
//type: A for Ally, E for Enemy
var links_data = [
 {"source": "Sylvester", "target": "Gordon", "type":"A" },
    {"source": "Sylvester", "target": "Lillian", "type":"A" },
    {"source": "Sylvester", "target": "Mary", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Sylvester", "target": "Jamie", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Sylvester", "target": "Jessie", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Sylvester", "target": "Helen", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Helen", "target": "Gordon", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mary", "target": "Lillian", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Ashton", "target": "Mary", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Duncan", "target": "Jamie", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gordon", "target": "Jessie", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Sylvester", "target": "Fray", "type":"E"},
    {"source": "Fray", "target": "Mauer", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fray", "target": "Cynthia", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fray", "target": "Percy", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Percy", "target": "Cynthia", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Infante", "target": "Duke", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Duke", "target": "Gordon", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Duke", "target": "Sylvester", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Baron", "target": "Duke", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Baron", "target": "Sylvester", "type":"E"},
    {"source": "Evette", "target": "Sylvester", "type":"E"},
    {"source": "Cynthia", "target": "Sylvester", "type":"E"},
    {"source": "Cynthia", "target": "Jamie", "type":"E"},
    {"source": "Mauer", "target": "Jessie", "type":"E"},
    {"source": "Duke", "target": "Lexy", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Feyton", "target": "Lexy", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Maria", "target": "Feyton", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Baron", "target": "Yvette", "type":"E"},
    {"source": "Evette", "target": "Maria", "type":"E"},
    {"source": "Cynthia", "target": "Yvette", "type":"E"},
    {"source": "Maria", "target": "Jamie", "type":"E"},
    {"source": "Maria", "target": "Lesley", "type":"E"},
    {"source": "Ashley", "target": "Damo", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Damo", "target": "Lexy", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Maria", "target": "Feyton", "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Finkler", "target": "Ashley", "type":"E"},
    {"source": "Sylvester", "target": "Maria", "type":"E"},
    {"source": "Peter", "target": "Finkler", "type":"E"},
    {"source": "Ashley", "target": "Gordon", "type":"E"},
    {"source": "Maria", "target": "Imogen", "type":"E"}
    
]


//set up the simulation and add forces  
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
     .nodes(nodes_data);
                              
var link_force =  d3.forceLink(links_data)
                        .id(function(d) { return d.name; });            
         
var charge_force = d3.forceManyBody()
    .strength(-100); 
    
var center_force = d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2);  
                      
simulation
    .force("charge_force", charge_force)
    .force("center_force", center_force)
    .force("links",link_force)
 ;

        
//add tick instructions: 
simulation.on("tick", tickActions );

//add encompassing group for the zoom 
var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "everything");

//draw lines for the links 
var link = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(links_data)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .style("stroke", linkColour);        

//draw circles for the nodes 
var node = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes") 
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes_data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", radius)
        .attr("fill", circleColour);
 
 
//add drag capabilities  
var drag_handler = d3.drag()
 .on("start", drag_start)
 .on("drag", drag_drag)
 //.on("end", drag_end); 
 
drag_handler(node);


//add zoom capabilities 
var zoom_handler = d3.zoom()
    .on("zoom", zoom_actions);

zoom_handler(svg);     

/** Functions **/

//Function to choose what color circle we have
//Let's return blue for males and red for females
function circleColour(d){
 if(d.sex =="M"){
  return "blue";
 } else {
  return "pink";
 }
}

//Function to choose the line colour and thickness 
//If the link type is "A" return green 
//If the link type is "E" return red 
function linkColour(d){
 if(d.type == "A"){
  return "green";
 } else {
  return "red";
 }
}

//Drag functions 
//d is the node 
function drag_start(d) {
 if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}

//make sure you can't drag the circle outside the box
function drag_drag(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function drag_end(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

//Zoom functions 
function zoom_actions(){
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}

function tickActions() {
    //update circle positions each tick of the simulation 
       node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
        
    //update link positions 
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: black ;
  stroke-width: 0px;
}

</style>
<svg width="800" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a filter on the nodes affected by a force using a filter on the nodes passed to the simulation in the `nodes()` call.

```
simulation.nodes(nodes.filter(function(d){return d.dragged === true;}))
```

If you want the node to exit the force immediately when the drag starts, you can have this happen in the drag start function after setting the dragged node's `.dragged` to `true`.